# Adjusting PTS when switching between streams

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, libavcodec, libav

My application needs to switch between two (or more) streams at the input while there is only one output (you could think about as a stream multiplexer). The frames from the input are decoded and then re-encoded again due to an overlay stuff.

So to arrange the AVFrame PTS I calculate an interval before encoding the frames. But the thing is when I switch between a RTMP stream and a MP4 file, the video is delayed a bit every time I switch. So, at the third switch the resulting stream is out of sync.

I don't know if I'm missing something I have to modify on the frame before encoding. I also though about creating an independent PTS for frames at the output but I don't know how to create it.

The input streams could have different FPS, timebases or codecs and the application must be able to deal with all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the root cause.

The problem was the MP4 file. With this type of file (for some reason) the video and audio packets are read in bug bunches (i.e.: 20 video packets and then 20 audio packets) whilst on a RTMP stream is more like (2 video and then 2 audio packets).
So the problem was the switch was being applied **before** reading all the bunch (i.e.: 20 video packets and 10 audio packets) so after that point the resulting stream is out of sync no matter what you do after that.

The solution I implemented waits until a decoded frame's type is different than the previous one. Then is when I perform the switch.

Comment: As I am looking to do the same thing (live input switching with an mp4) can you please provide some code? Thanks!

Comment: @user498529 Just check the frame type (AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO or AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO). Howeverthat's notthe preferred solution since the bunches can contain a lot of content.

A better solution will be buffering the content read from the file in two different buffers and get the audio/video frames by timestamp.